# CS50 Lab 6 world_cup issues with tournament function

Tags: python, cs50

I am working on CS50 Lab 6 and having problems with the `simulate_tournament()` function. I don't want the solution, just an idea of what I am doing incorrectly. The `simulate_tournament()` function should accept a list of teams and execute the `simulate_round()` function repeatedly until one winner is left. The simulate_round function returns a list of winners and `simulate_tournament()` returns one winner. I have completed all the other functions and only having issues with simulate_tournament.

```
# Simulate a sports tournament

import csv
import sys
import random
from collections import defaultdict

# Number of simluations to run
N = 1000


def main():

    # Ensure correct usage
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        sys.exit("Usage: python tournament.py FILENAME")

    teams = []
    # TODO: Read teams into memory from file
    file = sys.argv[1]
    with open(file,"r") as fil:
        reader = csv.DictReader(fil)

        for row in reader:
            name = row["team"]
            rating = int(row["rating"])
            teams += [name , rating]
            #x = [name , rating]
            #teams.append(x)

    counts = {}
    # TODO: Simulate N tournaments and keep track of win counts
    for i in range(N):
        teamname = simulate_tournament(teams)
        #counts[teamname] = counts.get(teamname, 0) + 1
        if teamname in counts:
            counts[teamname] += 1
        else:
            counts[teamname]  = 0
            counts[teamname] += 1


    # Print each team's chances of winning, according to simulation
    for team in sorted(counts, key=lambda team: counts[team], reverse=True):
        print(f"{team}: {counts[team] * 100 / N:.1f}% chance of winning")


def simulate_game(team1, team2):
    """Simulate a game. Return True if team1 wins, False otherwise."""
    rating1 = team1["rating"]
    rating2 = team2["rating"]
    probability = 1 / (1 + 10 ** ((rating2 - rating1) / 600))
    return random.random() < probability


def simulate_round(teams):
    """Simulate a round. Return a list of winning teams."""
    winners = []

    # Simulate games for all pairs of teams
    for i in range(0, len(teams), 2):
        if simulate_game(teams[i], teams[i + 1]):
            winners.append(teams[i])
        else:
            winners.append(teams[i + 1])

    return winners


def simulate_tournament(teams):
    """Simulate a tournament. Return name of winning team."""
    #TODO
    tournateams = teams
    while True:
        winns = simulate_round(tournateams)
        if len(winns) == 1:
            return winns[0]
        else:
            tournateams = winns

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You said: "_I am having issues with simulate_tournament_", but didn't describe the issues. Please add more details about the error.

Comment: What is not working in your code? Are you getting any errors? Is the output not what you expected? Please clarify what you mean with _having issues_

Comment: FYI, I tried to run your code, and get an error in `simulate_game()` (on line 57) when it is called from `simulate_round()`. You are trying to use a dictionary key to access the team's rating value, but the team object is a list.

Comment: Are you still working on this lab problem? Do you need help?

Comment: @kcw78 yes I still having probelms on this lab

Answer (score 0):

Spend some time examining the `teams` variable. When you read the csv file, you create `teams` as a list object with pairs of name, rating values. The resulting list looks like this for the men: `['Uruguay', 976, 'Portugal', 1306, 'France', 1166, ... ]` Then you call `simulate_tournament()`, which calls `simulate_round()` which calls `simulate_game(teams[i],teams[i+1])`. There (at least) are 2 problems with the last call.

1. When you call `simulate_game()` the first time, it will have `teams[0]='Uruguay'` and `teams[1]=976` (based on data above). Obviosuly, that won't work.
2. In `simulate_game()` you are using dictionary notation to access the rating (see `rating1 = team1["rating"]`, and the same for `rating2`). However these aren't dictionaries.

The problem specification says you should import each team's data as a dictionary, e.g., `{"team": "Uruguay", "rating": 976}`. It looks like you worked on this and abandoned it on lines 36-35. Fix this, and that will get `simulate_game()` working (and `_round()` and `_tournament()`). Once that is fixed, you also need to work on lines 43-47 to count the winners. Again, you are trying to use dictionary notation, and have some errors to fix. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the response but fortunately I fixed the issues yesterday. It works perfectly